# Group Conversation by latest message Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I can't seem to figure this out since mysql is not my strong suit. I've done a bit of research here but can't put two and two together, so I'm turning to the community for some help.

I am building a chat function inside my Laravel app where two users can talk to each other. I can't figure out how to build the inbox (group the conversations together) portion of things. I've figured out how to get last message grouped by sending it.

The following is inside my `User` Model:

```
public function lastMessages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'recipient_id')
        ->select('*')
        ->join(DB::raw('(Select max(id) as id from messages group by author_id) LatestMessage'), function($join) {
            $join->on('messages.id', '=', 'LatestMessage.id');
        })
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

My messages table consists of the following: `author_id`, `recipient_id`, `messaged`, `viewed`.

What I need to do is group messages, whether incoming our outgoing and display the latest message as inbox entry and once I click on that messages, the rest of the conversation pops up on the page.

My current sql shown above only gives me 1 last message, not the whole conversation.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you should keep the relationship function separate from logical(query) function. 
If I understood your question correctly , you should do something like this :

```
Message::where('recipient_id',$userid)->orWhere('author_id',$userid)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

This will give you messages send or received by user. Please clarify your question with `Author` and `Message` models if this is not what you want.

Comment: I have done that, but that gives me duplicates of entries in an array. If recipient id == $user id and if author_id == $user id, it will generate two duplicates, I have tried to groupBy recipient_id, but that omits author_id and vise versa. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I almost need to group by recipient and by author_id at the same time...